# Dolce the revues; solve this riddle

Tags: riddle

Solve this riddle:

Dolce the revues 
Whats' wrong with society? 
Fleets of walkers flock their feathers. 
Street of stalkers keep their boxers

Comment: Is the apostrophe in whats' significant? Or should it be what's?

Comment: What is there to solve?  Are we supposed to answer `What's wrong with society?` or the typical `Who/what am I`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> Cartoons?

Dolce the revues

> According to dictionary.com, [dolce](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dolce?s=t) means sweet or soft, and [revue](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/revue?s=t) means entertainment. Cartoons are entertainment that is kid-friendly (soft/sweet).

Whats' wrong with society?

> Cartoons are turning more and more stupid, no offense.

Fleets of walkers flock their feathers.

> ?

Street of stalkers keep their boxers

> ?

I am not sure, but I tried and this is my first attempt solving a riddle. :)

Comment: 2 unknown connections and 2 loose connections. I don't think it is the right answer.

Comment: I tried, and that's what counts. :)